# Отслеживание состояния процесса

Tags: c++

Можно ли создать программу, которая будит проводить мониторинг другого процесса на пример его изменения: inject и так далее - если возможно скажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: IMHO задача не для юзермода.

Comment: Полагаю, нужно что-то вроде анти-чит системы, хотя зачастую часть их кода встраивается в саму защищаемую программу

Comment: @Lyth можете посоветовать куда копать?программа которая нужно защитить на C# - не могу получить список dll в процессе

Answer (score -1):

Если вам уж очень интересно отслеживать процесс - Proccess Monitor
Для отслеживания используемых DLL - Dependency Walker